# Hide folder from Unity Dash search results

Tags: unity-dash, search, symbolic-link

I have some folders symlinked with Dropbox and whenever I search for files with the Unity Dash I get duplicate results.

Is there a way to prevent the Dropbox folder from being included in the search results? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

> > I'm aware of other questions with the same issue but none of them address my problem. 
> >     All of them refer to 'Privacy' setting in 12.04.
> >     I don't seem to have that setting in my system settings.

[image: no privacy setting]

Comment: Privacy settings should definitely be there, ask for how to get them back instead of duplicating your own question.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using 16.04 and i have the Security & Privacy app in system-settings so i think you have some missing packages somewhere.

Run this to check that you have ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-system-settings and their dependencies correctly installed and install them if needed.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-system-settings
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, It installed,  but still no sign of Privacy settings even after restart.