# Exclude folder from gnome search

Tags: gnome, 20.04, search

I use Dropbox and the folder is found in `/home/user`. The `/home/user/Documents` folder is a symlink to `/home/user/Dropbox/Documents` folder. When I search for files in Gnome Dash, if the search matches a file in Dropbox I get two entries - one for `/home/user/Dropbox/Documents/filepath` and another for `/home/user/Documents/filepath`.

How do I block one of these from appearing?

Comment: Do any of the suggestions here help? https://unix.stackexchange.com /questions/192095/modify-gnome-3-search-bar-results  -- totally different question but it might hold some clues to gnome search.

Comment: Also, this appears to be a true duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829867/hide-folder-from-unity-dash-search-results?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

First, install the dconf editor GUI  `apt-get install dconf-editor`. You may also use the command line tool with `gsettings set`

The key you want to edit is `/org/freedesktop/tracker/miner/files/ignored-directories`

Use a custom value here, make sure you don't remove the existing values. It might look like this:

```
['po', 'CVS', 'core-dumps', 'lost+found', '/home/user/Dropbox/Documents']
```

Another quick and easy method to ignore a folder is to place a `.trackerignore` file in the folder with `touch .trackerignore`. That won't work in your case.